# Should x.5 rounded to x or x+1?

Tags: rounding-unit

Say you have `300.5` dollars to pay as tax. Is there a mathematical concept that says rounding to `300` is better than `301` ?

Answer (score 1):

The two possible results are obtained under different *rounding modes* – they are specified in the IEEE 754 floating-point formats to give finer control over arithmetic calculations.

$300.5$ may round to $300$ if the mode is *round-to-even* or *round-to-zero*. It may round to $301$ if the mode is *round-away-from zero*.